# Regular panoramic photo to iPhone panoramic

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photography, panorama

How I can change the format or the register of a panoramic photo made in Photoshop to a iPhone panoramic photo, this is because the new feature of Facebook admit only that ones

Comment: Hi Nicolas, welcome to GD.SE. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Ok, i try to put a panoramic photo made whit a camera and photoshop in Facebook, but they only admit panoramic make with the cellphone @Luciano

Comment: have you [tried google](http://www.google.com/search?q=facebook+panoramic)? there are some clues to the answer there.

Comment: Yes...is why I try to ask here because there. Are no info about it

Comment: I can upload a panoramic, but Facebook only recognize if it is taken in a cellphone whit a panoramic function, is why I try to search the format of that file

Answer (score 4):

According to [this answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-upload-panoramic-pictures-on-Facebook-to-properly-display-full-panoramic-photographs), all you need to do is change the EXIF data of the image.

You'll need to download [ExifToolGUI v5.16](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/~bogdan/exiftoolgui516.zip) and [Download ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool-10.19.zip) to do the job (Windows only).

Using those tools Facebook will recognize your image as an interactive panorama.

Comment: i'll add a cross platform answer soon, stay tuned!

Comment: hi, tanks but is not working for me i change the make, like the tutorial but facebook don't recognize the panorama maybe is the phone... i don`t know

Comment: do not use the photo/video button, just drag and drop the file to the timeline.